# How to extract All files from Bitbucket repository using Bitbucket API

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I have tried below URL

https://bitbucket.org/ownername/projectname/src/5ec35d2481b3523123c43d5b2ddc105dd97b59fb/

I am getting Only  10 files from repo, but I have loaded 20 files , also I saw the response

it returns default pagelen 10, how to resolve this? , please help.

{"pagelen":10,"values":[{"path":"python_patterns","type":"commit_directory","

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution , its have some limitations , can give URL query param

https://bitbucket.org/!api/2.0/repositories/ownername/projectname/src?pagelen=100

minmum pagelen is 10 ,maximum is 100

refer this

https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Bworkspace%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/src/%7Bnode%7D/%7Bpath%7D

Answer (score 0):

You can add `limit` as query parameter to query more
This is for non cloud bitbucket server

```
https://{hostname:port}/rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectName}/repos/{reponame}/files?limit=1000
```